# DataTable "No data available in table" even if it have data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have to fill a datatable with some data I get from a google spreadsheet, i create the table in HTML and appends the rows with Jquery.

The problem is that when the datatable laods the first row says "No data available in table" even when the nexts rows have data.

This is part of the code Im using

//this function creates table rows and appends it to the table body

```
function displayUser() {

for (i = 0; i < userList.length; i++) {
    var $tblRow = $('<tr id="row' + i + '">');

    $tblRow.append('<td id="td' + i + '">' + userList[i][' inv-id']
        + '</td>');
    $tblRow.append('<td id="td' + i + '">' + userList[i]['inv-com-name']
        + '</td>');
    $tblRow.append('<td id="td' + i + '">' + userList[i]['inv-email']
        + '</td>');
    $tblRow.append('<td id="td' + i + '">' + userList[i]['email']
        + '</td>');
    $tblRow.append('<td id="td' + i + '">' + '<button onClick="editarUsuario(' + i + ')" class="btn btn-info btn-xs btn-edit">Edit</button>'
        + '</td>');
    $('#tbody').append($tblRow);
};
}
```

Also the html code for the table is this

```
<table id="dtVerticalScrollExample"
            class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm text-center table-fixed" cellspacing="0"
            width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="th-sm">ID
                    </th>
                    <th class="th-sm">Company
                    </th>
                    <th class="th-sm">Email
                    </th>
                    <th class="th-sm">User
                    </th>
                    <th class="th-sm">Action
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbody">

               *here is where the data is appended*

            </tbody>

        </table>
```

[Here is a imagen that shows that the table appears to be empty even when the data was appended by the script, the first row is the message of "No data available in table" and says 0 entries below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iel6j.png)

I expect the datatable to load and be filled by the script that get the data from the database. But what actual happens is that the frist row says the datatable is empty but it have data in the nexts rows.

Comment: Do you expect the database request to load instantly? It won't, because a database request is asynchronous and takes time. Could you instead make it say loading, and switch to the "No data available" message if no rows are returned?

Comment: I added an image showing the problem I'm having, the message of "No data available" appears in the first row even after the script append the data.
I thought that the problem was because the script run after the table loads, but then I dont know why the message keeps appearing.

Comment: you have an append -- that means the old line is still there.  you need to replace all the content with what you create.

Comment: Creating a table body and appending it to the table would be enough?
Or I would have to create the whole data table in the jquery?

Answer (score 2):

Yes the problem was that the old content was still there even after the appends.

I found a way to solve it.
In order to replace the content with the one I created, I had to destroy and initialize the table in the jquery.

```
function displayUser() {

var table = $('#dtVerticalScrollExample').DataTable();
table.destroy();

for (i = 0; i < userList.length; i++) {
    var $tblRow = $('<tr id="row' + i + '"/>');

    $tblRow.append('<td id="td' + i + '">' + userList[i][' inv-id'] + '</td>');
    $tblRow.append('<td id="td' + i + '">' + userList[i]['inv-com-name'] + '</td>');
    $tblRow.append('<td id="td' + i + '">' + userList[i]['inv-email'] + '</td>');
    $tblRow.append('<td id="td' + i + '">' + userList[i]['email'] + '</td>');
    $tblRow.append('<td id="td' + i + '">' + '<button onClick="edit(' + i + ')" class="btn btn-info btn-xs btn-edit">Edit</button>' + '</td>');

    $('#dtVerticalScrollExample').append($tblRow);

};
var table = $('#dtVerticalScrollExample').DataTable();
```

}